# How can I send id to controller action method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working a project and I had some trouble. I want to send id from html `beginform` but I couldn't do it.

I want to send `/BuyTourTicket/tourid`

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult TourTicket(int id)
{
    var tour = db.TBLTUR.Find(id);
    ViewBag.tourid = tour.id;
    ViewBag.tourname = tour.tur_basligi.ToString();
    ViewBag.kalkisYeri = tour.kalkis_yeri.ToString();
    ViewBag.tarih = tour.tarih.ToString();
    ViewBag.detaylar = tour.detay.ToString();
    ViewBag.turYetkilisi = db.TBLTURYETKILISI.Find(id).ad + " " + db.TBLTURYETKILISI.Find(id).soyad;

    return View("TourTicket",tour);
}

public ActionResult BuyTourTicket()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuyTourTicket(int id)
{
    TBLTURREZERVASYON reservation = new TBLTURREZERVASYON();
    reservation.tur = id;

    db.TBLTURREZERVASYON.Add(reservation);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

[image]

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: I fixed but can't add cshtml part corrupt while adding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, the default route usually describes the `id` parameter as optional. Therefore change the action method declaration to `public ActionResult BuyTourTicket(int? id)`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuyTourTicket(int? id)
{
    TBLTURREZERVASYON reservation = new TBLTURREZERVASYON();
    reservation.tur = id;
    db.TBLTURREZERVASYON.Add(reservation);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

The second, change the parameters order in the `Html.BeginForm()` of the `TourTicket.cshtml` to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BuyTourTicket", "Tur", new { id = ViewBag.tourid }, FormMethod.Post))
```

The route values are third parameter and the HTTP method is the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix an action route

```
[HttpPost("{id"})]
 public ActionResult BuyTourTicket(int id)
```

and add Get to another action

```
[HttGet]
public ActionResult BuyTourTicket()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I give a mistake. -> 'HttpPostAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Ömer What do you mean?

Comment: I am sorry i missed something the first solutions is working